# UPDATING mysql data using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to display a Website Title on my Home Page. This website title is stored in the database named `mywebsite` and in table `settings`. I want to update this with an `input type text`'s value. The title is displayed perfectly but when I write something in the text field and submit it, the database doesn't update. I think I am doing everything right and there isn't any error displaying on my page, but still it is not working. Can anyone figure out the error?
Here's my code:

```
<?php
// Some database detail
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'mywebsite';
// Making connection
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

// Making a sql query for "Website Title" and saving it in variable $query
$query = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE NameOfSetting='Website Title'";

// Applying query
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

// Fetching data from database
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $title = $_POST['text'];
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE settings SET TheSetting=$title WHERE NameOfSetting='Website Title'");
}
?>

<h1><?php echo $row['TheSetting']; ?></h1>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Change the title" name="text">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT:**  When I enter any numbers in the field and then submit and refresh it works fine but it's only working with numbers not with alphabets. I don't know why?

Comment: `SET TheSetting='$title'`

Comment: You are Selecting before Updating, so `<?php echo $row['TheSetting']; ?>` will always be the old value, not the new value. Move your `UPDATE` before your `SELECT`

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are the boss you got the problem thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

`SET TheSetting=$title`

`$title` needs to be wrapped in quotes:

`SET TheSetting='$title'`

Sidenote: You may also want to change this line (*as a security precaution*):

```
$title = $_POST['text'];
```

to:

```
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['text']);
```

Comment: Hey I'm a beginner. And trying to figure out how `cms`'s are made. Would you guide me. Is this the concept of how permenant changes are made through front-end? Or is it a bad practice? Please guide me I am 15 and started learning php!

Comment: Oh Lordy, wish I could help but I know next to nothing about CMS's @user41510 I hard code everything I do.

Comment: Plus, seeing that this solved your problem, do mark as accepted by clicking the White checkmark till it turns Green. @user41510 so we can close the question.

Comment: To somewhat answer your question, that is how SQL works. Once the DB has been (successfully) updated, it's done until it's updated again, so basically that's how it's done. @user41510 You could also look into [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) which is a more secure method.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always do some sort of error checking. I.e. using or die(mysqli_error);

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database)or die(mysqli_error);
```

This will atleast give you an idea of what your proplem is. Use this error checking method every time you connect, query, or close a database.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to help.

Comment: I understand. You're presently mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` --- `mysql_error` should read as `mysqli_error` ;-)

Comment: note - `mysqli_error` requires the connection link identifier -> `mysqli_error($con)` http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

**use this code it will solve your problem.**

```
  <?php
    // Some database detail
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'mywebsite';
    // Making connection
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database)or die(mysqli_error());

    // Making a sql query for "Website Title" and saving it in variable $query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE NameOfSetting='Website Title'";

    // Applying query
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    // Fetching data from database
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $title = $_POST['text'];
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE settings SET TheSetting='".$title."' WHERE NameOfSetting='Website Title'");
    }
    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $row['TheSetting']; ?></h1>

    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Change the title" name="text">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: This is still incorrect. `"UPDATE settings SET TheSetting=".$title." WHERE ...` is the same as `"UPDATE settings SET TheSetting=$title WHERE ...`. The issue is the OP needs to quote the value -> `'$title'`

Comment: ya i corrected it that was silly mistake made by me. I used double quote instead of single

Comment: Closer, but now you need to either remove the dots `'.$title.'` -> `'$title'`, or add the double quotes back in -> `'".$title."'`

Comment: also, `or die(mysql_error());` should be `or die(mysqli_error($con));` -> `mysqli` vs `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE settings SET TheSetting='$title' WHERE NameOfSetting='Website Title'");
```

Comment: Hey I'm a beginner. And trying to figure out how cms's are made. Would you guide me. Is this the concept of how permenant changes are made through front-end? Or is it a bad practice? Please guide me I am 15 and started learning php!